# How to disable NGINX logging with file

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am very new to Nginx and noticed that whenever I hit my server locally it logs. I was wondering, what config files do I need to create (and where do I put them) and what do I have to put into them to disable that behavior (I am trying to prevent spew). I am running my application on aws and am getting a lot of log lines of the form '172.31.22.19 - - [23/Jun/2021:23:38:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3022 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"' Is there a way to disable that? Or do I need to disable everything?

My docker file is:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:16 AS builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app


# install app dependencies
#copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package.json ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install


# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

#Stage 2
#######################################
#pull the official nginx:1.19.0 base image
FROM nginx:1.19.0
#copies React to the container directory
# Set working directory to nginx resources directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static resources
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copies static resources from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
EXPOSE 80
# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I can successfully run the above with  'docker run -p 80:80 my-app'

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a docker run command to run the container then add the flag `--log-driver none` to the run command

Looking at your dockerfile youre running node and nginx in a single container. I would advise against this and seperate them into seperate containers using docker-compose

if you do this then add the line `driver: none` to the service running the nginx container

Comment: Hi @richardsefton thank you! Where do I add the 'driver: none'? Is that in the docker file? Or somewhere else?

Comment: `driver: none` would be for the docker-compose.yaml file. but for that you should seperate your containers into an nginx and node containers. setting the log driver for the container as it is in your dockerfile is will probably stop the logs from your node app too.

Comment: if you are reverse proxying with nginx, docker-compose networks the two containers together so you could reverse proxy to http://<nodecontainerservicename>:<app_port>

Comment: nm. I just reread it. You're building and copying the app built with node and serving im guessing as static files? just add `--log-driver none` to your docker run command

Comment: I tried 'docker run --log-driver none -p 80:80 myapp' but I still get logs of the form: 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: try running the container with docker-compose with the `driver: none` flag. If you're not familiar you can find a boilerplate compose file online and edit it to fit. To use your own dockerfile just use the use `build: /path/to/your/dockerfile` instead of `image: `

Comment: Is there a way to disable these logs by including some file that will be picked up by nginx that simply tells it not to log all incoming requests?

Comment: not to my knowledge. You could also try running the container detached (`-d` flag)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a nginx.conf file (see below) and changing the value of access_log to 'off'. I describe the steps I took

1. get the nginx.conf file:
   Per [What is the 'default' nginx.conf that comes with docker Nginx image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68108898/what-is-the-default-nginx-conf-that-comes-with-docker-nginx-image/68109019#68109019) do the following:

```
# Create a temporary container
docker run -d --rm --name mynginx nginx

# Copy the nginx configuration in the container
docker cp mynginx:/etc/nginx .
```

2. create nginx.conf file in root of project. Mine was:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

3. Modify Dockefile to (note the 'COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf'):

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:16 AS builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app


# install app dependencies
#copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package.json ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install


# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

#Stage 2
#######################################
#pull the official nginx:1.19.0 base image
FROM nginx:1.19.0
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
#copies React to the container directory
# Set working directory to nginx resources directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static resources
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copies static resources from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
EXPOSE 80
# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```