# What is the 'default' nginx.conf that comes with docker Nginx image?

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to figure out what the nginx.conf file is that comes with the nginx image. Does anyone know where I find that (or how can I determine what that is)? For instance, fi I have 'FROM nginx:1.19.0' - what nginx config does that have?

Comment: Did you [try reading the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)? It is right there: "*If you wish to adapt the default configuration, use something like the following to copy it from a running nginx container ...*".

Comment: Ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get details from dockerHub:

[nginx:1.19](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nginx/library/nginx/1.19/images/sha256-32382c05ebf536d9419e52e048ddf4c0ff9d65ebbd8596d77fed5b4b35980ecb?context=explore)

If you want to get the nginx.conf in the docker container, you can do this:

```
 # Create a temporary container
 docker run -d --rm --name mynginx nginx

 # Copy the nginx configuration in the container
 docker cp mynginx:/etc/nginx .
```